# How to wait for canvas loaded with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

In my project, I need to take a screenshot of an element including a canvas, and the canvas is
rendering some charts, I should wait for the charts complete loading then to take the screenshot,
How can I do this?
I tried the webdriver waits functions, and the canvas is visible but the rendering charts are still loading.
[canvas content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ETp.png)

Comment: is their any loading icon? then wait for invisibility of that.

Comment: @murali selenium Great, thx!!